# Can't update item on Express and React

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, react-redux

I created a route here where in I am planning to post or update on this route via `updateResortOwner`:

```
router.route('/:userid').get(getOwnerResorts, resortOwner).post(protect, resortOwner, createOwnerResort)
router.route('/:userid/:id').get(getResortOwnerById).put(protect, resortOwner, updateResortOwner).delete(protect, resortOwner, deleteResortOwner)
```

On my controller I have this:

```
// @description   Update a resort
// @route         PUT /api/resorts/:userid
// @access        Private/Admin
const updateResortOwner = expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {

    const { 
        name, 
        price_per_night, 
        description,
        address, 
        city, 
        province, 
        zip_code,
        latitude,
        longitude,
        phone,
        website,
        amenities,
        image
     } = req.body

    const resort = await Resort.findById(req.params.id)

    if(resort){
        resort.name = name,
        resort.price_per_night = price_per_night
        resort.description = description
        resort.address = address
        resort.city = city
        resort.province = province
        resort.zip_code = zip_code
        resort.latitude = latitude
        resort.longitude = longitude
        resort.phone = phone
        resort.website = website
        resort.amenities = amenities
        resort.image = image

        const updatedResort = await resort.save()
        res.json(updatedResort)
    } else{
        res.status(404)
        throw new Error('Resort not found!')
    }
})
```

In order to make this work on my redux action:

```
export const updateResortOwner = (resort) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    try {
        dispatch({ type: RESORT_OWNER_UPDATE_REQUEST })
        
        const { userLogin: { userInfo } } = getState()

        const config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`
            }
        }

        const { data } = await axios.post(`/api/resorts/${userInfo._id}/${resort._id}`, resort,  config)

        dispatch({
            type: RESORT_OWNER_UPDATE_SUCCESS,
            payload: data
        })
    
    } catch (error) {
       dispatch({
           type: RESORT_OWNER_UPDATE_FAIL,
           payload: error.response && error.response.data.message ? 
           error.response.data.message : error.message
       })
    }
}
```

And then on my submithandler on the frontend:

```
const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    dispatch(updateResortOwner({ 
        _id: resortId,
        name,
        price_per_night: pricePerNight,
        description,
        address,
        city,
        province,
        zip_code: zipCode,
        phone,
        email,
        website,
        image,
        amenities: {
            tv,
            reservation,
            moderate_noise: moderateNoise,
            free_wifi: freeWifi,
            trendy,
            credit_card: creditCard,
            bar,
            animals,
            kids
        }
    }))
}
```

When I submit this its returning this error:

```
Not found - /api/resorts/5fe92b7a1ecf1a16e8ced784/5fe1798bebef0c2db08d4c76
```

Any idea what's happening here? How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you elaborate more and tell me specifically the exact order or route to put?

Comment: there is no post request in your router for `router.route('/:userid/:id')` just add post request along with delete, put and get request, and you are doing post request in redux action `await axios.post(`/api/resorts/${userInfo._id}/${resort._id}``

Comment: Isnt there is `put` in there? would that not work to update the data?

Comment: how it will work when you do post request? just do post to put. when i call your name `xyz` you will not listen because your name is `Marc Solva`

Comment: Man you are amazing! Thanks